# Jsoup matching tag with column

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

for a school project i need to parse arXiv.org API response code, to harvest some informations.
I'm using Jsoup and i'm stuck on a problem:

I have a tag like this:

```
String value = document.select("arxiv:comment").text();
```

But this give me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'arxiv:comment': unexpected token at ':comment'
```

Comment: can you add the dom that you want to parse? `arxiv:comment` is an invalid query expression

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

The right syntax to match a tag like `<tag:aa>..</tag:aa>` is:

`$document.select("tag|aa").text();`